# Ionic 4 ,Add custom component on modal page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

About Ionic 4
I set up a custom component and it appears on all pages, but does not appear on a Modal page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you have to make a `SharedModule` for custom components.

Comment: thanks a lot, I make SharedModule according to your recommendation and it works great.
Thanks